# What is this "*ptrList [100] " inside the class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently, I have seen this code:

```
class Student; // forward declaration
class Teacher
{
     friend void registration(Teacher &t, Student &s);
  public: 
     void setGrades(); // sets students' grades
  protected:
     int numStudents;
     Student *ptrList[100]; // <--- ???
};
```

That looks like a mixture of pointer and array...
Usually, it is either     `int *ptr`  or     `int array[10]`
I have never seen something like this. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Your observation is correct.  It is an array, and each element inside the array is a pointer.  Just like you may have seen arrays of different type already, such as `int` and `double`, now you see an array of `Student*`.

Comment: It is an *array of pointers [100 of them]* to type `Student`.

Comment: The follow-on question is: This is an array with pointers inside.  Can you have a pointer with an array inside?  Answer: Yes, it would look like `Student (*ptrList)[100]` and then it would be a pointer to a contiguous array of 100 Student objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of pointers to type `Student`. Think about it this way:

A typical declaration for an array in C++ is:
     name [elements];
In the provided example the `<type>` used for the elements of the array is `Student*`, which is a pointer to type `Student`.